# I'm having serious problems with network connections

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.04

My wireless connection breaks very often. My computer doesn't show that it's disconnected, but software that needs network connection don't work. The network starts working again when I reconnect to the network. This problem appears with every WiFi I connect to and only on my laptop. I'm using Ubuntu 17.04. I hope that someone can help me with my problem. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Running `sudo lshw -class network` results in:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: a8:a7:95:b8:1a:2f
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.10.0-20-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.121 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:121 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:91200000-91203fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 07
       serial: c8:5b:76:0a:a2:1e
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:117 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:91100000-91100fff memory:91000000-91003fff
```

Comment: you need to contact the wi-fi mfg.

Comment: What do you mean, Greg?

Comment: Can you connect with that computer from a different OS? That way you could identify if the problem is hardware or software related. If it would work in another OS, then you have a problem with driver, I guess.

Comment: Ill try.  Does it matter if it's other Linux or is something like Windows better?